# Nginx load balancing redirects to upstream "name"

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, configuration, openshift-online-2

### Introduction:

Please read this serverfault question on [nginx load balancing issue with 301 from backend](https://serverfault.com/questions/380480/nginx-load-balancing-issue-with-301-from-backend). Somewhat similar to my problem, but the answer doesn't work. Nginx is redirecting to the "name" of my upstream. The point is, this isn't an OpenShift-specific question.

---

### Configuration:

I setup nginx 1.4.4 correctly (built from source, verified that it works properly [1]) on one DIY unscaled gear with OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP 127.8.143.129. Let's call it A. I setup one Tornado server on said gear, and another Tornado on another unscaled gear. (Suppose a gear = red hat linux box on same LAN behind NAT, simplified) Both are simple hello-world apps based on the [openshift-hellotornado repo](https://github.com/giulivo/openshift-hellotornado). Let's call this B. B's DNS address is pam-picaxe.rhcloud.com. A's DNS address is main-picaxe.rhcloud.com.

Whenever I'm browsing to main-picaxe.rhcloud.com, the browser is redirected with a 302 Found with

```
Location: https://frontends/app.
```

"frontends" here is the name of the upstream in nginx's config. Weird.

[1]: Proof that nginx works with just gear A: If I comment out line 20 and uncomment line 21 in the configuration file (pastebin link at end of post), everything works well and I get a "Hello world!". but whenever I have a case like line 20 (even if it's the DNS address of gear A instead of gear B).

### Tried a solution:

I've spent half a day on this, tired of trying to configure this. I tried the solution given in the aforementioned serverfault post, by replacing my location block with:

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect http://frontends http://$host:$server_port/;
            proxy_redirect http://frontends:8080/ http://$host:$server_port/;
}
```

This results in a redirect loop. Sample log output starting from first request to /:

```
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD - - [22/Dec/2013:14:53:53 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ"
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD - - [22/Dec/2013:14:53:55 -0500] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 302 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ"
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD - - [22/Dec/2013:14:53:55 -0500] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 302 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ"
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD - - [22/Dec/2013:14:53:55 -0500] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 302 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ"
AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD - - [22/Dec/2013:14:53:56 -0500] "GET /app HTTP/1.1" 302 331 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31" "WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ"
```

Any ideas on how I can have a normal load-balanced life with nginx?

Link to nginx.conf: http://pastebin.com/91CMftSc

Comment: Where is your `upstream` defined?

Comment: @MichaelHampton you mean in the configuration file? Edited the question to make the link more visible; here it is again: http://pastebin.com/91CMftSc

Comment: What you have in pastebin doesn't match what's in your question. I would start over and make sure you have spelled everything correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, oops, my bad, thank you! I made the corrections. It's always 'frontends'.

Comment: Turns out this was an OpenShift problem. Beware of their DNS tricks and firewalls. It was done for our own good though, better isolation.